# What kind of path for paper-card image?

Tags: image, cordova, polymer

I'm trying to build a Android App using Polymer and Cordova.

How do I have to style the image path in paper-card elements, or do I have to edit a config somewhere?

The web-version works just fine, but after building the app with cordova, the image path is like in `files://assets/../images/img01.png`, but only like `/images/img01.png` which can't be found by Android. The image exists in the asset folder.

I have no custom build configurations for cordova or anything like this.

Polymer code:

```
<paper-card image="../../images/img01.png">
  <div class="card-content">
    <!-- content -->  
  </div>
</paper-card>
```

Comment: Did you try [resolveUrl](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/api/Polymer.Base#method-resolveUrl)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like [a1626](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5976073/a1626) pointed out, `resolveUrl()` does the trick.
Called it in the function for the `google-map-ready` listener.